# Open scene from Push notifications

Tags: ios, notifications, storyboard, push

I have a storyboard like this:

[My Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dk0CM.png)

I need to open the scene shown in the above image when you receive a push notification. I tried this way:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication*)app didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    NotificationsViewController *notificationobject = [[NotificationsViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:notificationobject animated:YES];
    gotNotifcation = YES;   
}
```

But only it opens the NavigationControll black. How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have NotificationsViewController in your storyboard but I'm not certain the object you are doing an alloc & init on is the same view controller.

Try doing this instead:

```
// replace everything between the quotes with the correct name & identifiers
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"myStoryboardName" bundle:nil];
NotificationsViewController *vc = (NotificationsViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myNotificationsViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:notificationObject animated:YES];
gotNotification = YES;
```

OR, since there appears to be a segue there to get you to your storyboard, try doing:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueIdentifier" sender:self];
```